# Nodejs: Served html page not linked to css

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have the following basic script running in nodejs to serve up an html file with an associated css stylesheet:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var serverPort = 8080;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

console.log('request starting ...');
var extname = path.extname(request.url);

var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
    case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
    }

fs.readFile('js/EmailDisplay/htm/index.html', function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.writeHead(500);
        response.end();
    } else {
        console.log(contentType);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
        response.end(content,'utf-8');
    }
});
});

server.listen(serverPort);
console.log('Server running at localhost:' + serverPort +"/");
```

If I open the file in Firefox (File->Open File), it renders properly.  If I go to localhost:8080 the index page is served but without the style applied to it.  Why?  The console.log in the fs.readFile block shows me that both files are being read.

PS - I know there are packages that will let me do this blindly (eg. 'connect') but I'm trying to understand what is actually happening before going that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies probably in this line:

```
 fs.readFile('js/EmailDisplay/htm/index.html', function(error, content) {
```

You're reading and returning to the client the same html file, even when `.js` and `.css` are requested.

You should probably set the path to the file along its content type in the switch you have earlier in your code.

Comment: Got it working, so big thanks!  I'm a javascript/node/html/css noob on a pretty steep learning curve.  Coming from Matlab I'm still just realising how low level nodejs (w/o packages) is, and how important paths are.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with nodejs and express. See my sample `server.js` below

```
var express= require("express");
var app= express();
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile("testing.html", {root: "."});
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Static content can be added by including the line:

```
app.use(express.static("foundation-5.4.6", {index: false}));
```

This uses [express.static](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static). In my case, I'm serving static css and js from the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework, but you can easily modify this to your specific `public` folder.